# Rebex SFTP error in C#: Permission denied on PutFile

Tags: c#, sftp, rebex

```
string msg = "Writing to file.";
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg);
System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
ftpClient.PutFile(mem,"file.txt");
```

While I connect with no issue, I've been receiving this exception that I don't quite understand:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Rebex.Net.SftpException' occurred in Rebex.Sftp.dll
>
> Additional information: Permission denied; Permission denied."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says that you do not have permissions for the operation. Probably you do not have permissions to create/write the file.

It can easily be caused by an absence of a path in your `PutFile` call. It may try to upload the file to a file system root, where only `root` can write.

Try using a full path, like `/home/user/file.txt`.